# Is it possible to do this in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a datasheet like

```
... |   dests   | ... 
----------------------
... |  a, b, c  | ... 
... |  a, b     | ... 
... |  a        | ...
... |  a, d     | ...
... |  b        | ...
```

and I want to convert it to the form

```
... |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  | 
-----------------------------------------
... |  X  |  X  |  X  |     | 
... |  X  |  X  |     |     | 
... |  X  |     |     |     | 
... |  X  |     |     |  X  | 
... |     |  X  |     |     |
```

or have a filter like

```
dests 
       a
       b
       c
       d
```

which I can use to select combinations of the possible `dests`.

Is this possible? How would I do it?

Comment: are you looking for a formula or vba?

Comment: @ScottCraner Formula

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C$1,$A1)),"X","")
```

[image]